# Knockout doesn't use supplied view model instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I have a knockout component that I add to the page. I am trying to call `ko.applyBindings` with an instance of the view model that I created. But knockout seems to ignore it and create its own instance.

Code:

```
ko.components.register("my-component", {viewModel: MyViewModel, template: "....."});
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(this.config), document.getElementsByTagName("my-component")[0]);
```

I have a `console.log` in the constructor of `MyViewModel` and I am seeing that two instances are created: One with the parameters I pass and one without. And knockout seems to be using the one without.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components actually have their own view models by design. You can, however, pass them an instance of a viewmodel you've created earlier:

```
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(this.config);
ko.components.register("my-component", { viewModel: { instance: myViewModel }});
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: It's more or less the only way. I think the idea was that if you already have a view-model created then a component might not be the right solution as you can just use the template binding instead. Passing an existing instance was added as an afterthought